# Using the `gcloud` CLI to prove a user's identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to know whether it's possible to verify a user's identity using the `gcloud` command.

The first idea I had was to ask them to run `gcloud auth list`, which gives output similar to:

```
$ gcloud auth list
       Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       john.smith@somewhere.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

The problem with this approach is that a user can just edit the output to lie about their identity (E.g. `bob.ross` can just replace their name with `john.smith` to fake the proof).

The `gcloud` CLI also has `print-access-token` and `print-identity-token`... Is it possible to use these tokens to check if a user are who they really say they are?

I've tried googling, but haven't found anything relevant yet... most articles just point you to `gcloud auth login` ...

Comment: This is a clear XY problem, please explain the problem that you are trying to solve, I can guarantee you "parsing the text output of gcloud" is not the solution, but you only talk about that, not your actual problem. You want someone to prove their identity, sure, but where, in what situation.

Comment: @somethingsomething, I anticipated someone might bring up the XY problem. I do however, want to see the answer to the question as I have asked it, because it might be useful in a different future problem. The answer might also be useful for other people.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `print-identity-token` and then verify the OIDC Identity Token signature using the public certificate. That would verify the identity (email address) the user authenticated with in Google. The user cannot modify the contents without invalidating the signature.

There are many articles about how to verify OIDC token signatures including answers on Stack Overflow.

You are using the wording **User's Identity**. You can only verify the identity stored in Google. Google does not verify who a user says they are (in most cases) such as matching a driver's license, passport, etc.

Comment: Thanks - will test it out tomorrow and approve the answer tomorrow